# Convert RenderTargetBitmap to Bitmap

Tags: wpf, vb.net, system.drawing, rendertargetbitmap

This looks like a dup question, it is, but no one has answered the actual question(s).

Here goes:
Basically, I'm rendering a ViewPort3D as a 2D snapshot in code, but need to convert that type 
`RenderTargetBitmap` into the type `System.Drawing.Bitmap` (for further processing on the 2D side).

```
Dim bmpRen As New RenderTargetBitmap(1024, 550, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32)
bmpRen.Render(Me.vp3dTiles) 'render the viewport as 2D snapshot
```

While I know how to save it to a file, I'd rather skip that step and convert the `bmpRen` to a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` type, but there is no method to do so.

Comment: Don't use `System.Drawing` stuff in WPF.

Comment: @FedericoBerasategui things such as tray icon still need GDI stuff for Win32 API.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`RenderedTargetBitmap` is a `BitmapSource`, so the `BmpBitmapEncoder` can do the conversion for us:

This is in C#, but it should translate to VB without any problems.

```cs
RenderTargetBitmap bmpRen = new RenderTargetBitmap(1024, 550, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
bmpRen.Render(vp3dTiles);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
BitmapEncoder encoder = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bmpRen));
encoder.Save(stream);

Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(stream);
```

Comment: Use `PngBitmapEncoder` with `PixelFormats.Pbgra32` if you need alpha / transparency.